# Why oligohydramnios leads to hypoplasia of lung?

Tags: lungs, pathophysiology, congenital, amniotic-cavity

What I found for the question is that due to -

- Oligohydramnios reduces the intrathoracic cavity size, thus disrupting fetal lung growth and leading to pulmonary hypoplasia.
- decreased fetal breathing movements, and
- decreased extrinsic stretch due to fluid
  in alveoli leads to hypoplasia of lung.[here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1875957216300626)

I get the the decreased extrinsic stretch part but **how come fetal breathing movements decrease with oligohydramnios?** Is it because friction increases or something else?

Secondly, **how oligohydramnios leads to decreased intrathoracic size?** Is it because less fluid is swallowed in or something else is in play?